# How to deduce the boundary for heat ball?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Here:

https://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/heat-ball-and-heat-sphere-mean-value-property/

It's given a reasoning that gives out the heat ball interior and its boundary, separated.

However, I have troubles seeing, why must the boundary be that?

---

Can one perhaps use the reasoning that since $y$ grows to the positive direction and since the inequality limits $y$ from above, then $y$s at the boundary satisfy the equality part of the inequality?

However, how do I know that $y$ actually attains that value?

Comment: So, what is your doubt? The "non-symmetric form" of heat equation require the "ball" has to be somehow non-symmetric I mean $t$ and $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ are quite different, while $x_1,x_3,\cdots,x_n$ in Laplace equation $\Delta u=0$ are identical.

Comment: @Icesea Whether the boundary is attained and why must it exist in the equality part?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what is your question. The article there is very clear now.

Comment: @Icesea How does the article infer what the boundary is?

Comment: Intuitively, consider $n=2$, for each $s$, then $y$ traces out a circle centered at $x$ of some radius determined by $s$ and $t$.